# React JS : Unable to search the data in the grid(table) as per the search criteria

Tags: reactjs, full-text-search

I am a Beginner in React Js and have been working on it for the past 3 weeks , For now I am able to get the data from the form elements, pass it to an API via fetch and get the results obtained in a Grid / Tabular format , But I am trying to implement search criteria on the table, If I search for a specific name or text only that row should be displayed as opposed to all of the rows, I used the code snippet available online for a Javascript module and made modifications accordingly but have not been successful . Your inputs are welcome.

```js
  import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
    import {
      Panel,
      Button,
      Col,
      PageHeader,
      ControlLabel,
      FormControl,
      HelpBlock,
      FormGroup,
      Checkbox,
      Form,
      Radio,
      InputGroup,
      Glyphicon
    } from 'react-bootstrap';

    import FormControlFeedback from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControlFeedback';
    import FormControlStatic from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControlStatic';
    import InputGroupAddon from 'react-bootstrap/lib/InputGroupAddon';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          respData: []
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this
        this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
        this.setArrow = this.setArrow.bind(this);
        this.onSort = this.onSort.bind(this);
      }

      handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const form = event.target;
        const data = new FormData(form);
        const arrayValue = [];
        var i = 0;
        console.log('Data from Form:', data);
        for (let name of data.keys()) {
          const input = form.elements[name];
          const parserName = input.dataset.parse;
          const parsedValue = data.get(name);
          console.log('name', name);
          console.log('parsedValue', parsedValue);
          if (typeof parsedValue == 'undefined' || parsedValue == null) {
            console.log('Not Undefined or Not Null');
            arrayValue[i] = '';
            data.set(name, arrayValue[i]);
          } else {
            data.set(name, parsedValue);
            arrayValue[i] = parsedValue;
          }

          i = i + 1;
        }

        var response_data = '';
        var response_jsonObj;
        var txt = '';
        var req = {
          RequestString: [
            {
              field1: arrayValue[0],
              field2: arrayValue[1],
              field3: arrayValue[2],
              field4: arrayValue[3],
              field5: arrayValue[4],
              field6: arrayValue[5],
              field7: arrayValue[6],
              field8: arrayValue[7],
              field9: arrayValue[8],
              field10: arrayValue[9],
              field11: arrayValue[10],
              field12: arrayValue[11],
              field13: arrayValue[12]
            }
          ]
        };

        console.log('req string :' + req);

        fetch('API_URL', {
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, application/xml,  */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
          },
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(req)
        })
          .then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
              console.log('Problem in fetching');
              return;
            }
            //  this.setState({respData: response.data});

            response.text().then(data => {
              console.log('Data in Console', data);
              response_data = data;
              console.log('Response Data', response_data);
              response_jsonObj = JSON.parse(response_data);
              console.log('Response JSON Object', response_jsonObj);
            });
          })
          .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
      }

      searchFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("search");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        console.log('input in searchFunction:',input);
        console.log('filter in searchFunction:',filter);
        table = document.getElementById("Search-Table");
        console.log('table in searchFunction:',table);
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        searchData = this.state.customerData.map((item, i) => {
          const ID = item.Field1;
          const Name = item.Field2;
          var compName = Name.toString();
          console.log('Name in search function:',Name);
          console.log('compName in search function:',compName);
          console.log('filter === Name',(filter === compName));
          if (filter === compName ){

            this.setState({respData:searchData});
          }

        });

} 


      onSort = (column) => (e) => {
            const direction = this.state.sort.column ? (this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc') : 'desc';
            const sortedData = this.state.respData.sort((a, b) => {
              if (column === 'Field1') {
                const nameA = a.Field1.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
                const nameB = b.Field1.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
                if (nameA < nameB) {
                  return -1;
                }
                if (nameA > nameB) {
                  return 1;
                }

                // names must be equal
                return 0;
              }
            });




            if (direction === 'desc') {
              sortedData.reverse();
            }

            this.setState({
              respData: sortedData,
              sort: {
                  direction,
                    column,
        }
            });
          };

          setArrow = (column,className) => {
            let current_className = className;

            if (this.state.sort.column === column) {
              current_className += this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? ' asc' : ' desc';
            }

            console.log(current_className);

            return current_className;
          };
      render() {
        return (
          <div id="SampleDiv">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <table cellspacing="30">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 1</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field1"
                        name="field1"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 2</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field2"
                        name="field2"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 3</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field3"
                        name="field3"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 4</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field4"
                        name="field4"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 5</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field5"
                        name="field5"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 6</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field6"
                        name="field6"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 7</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field7"
                        name="field7"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 8</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field8"
                        name="field8"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 9</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field9"
                        name="field9"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 10</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field10"
                        name="field10"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 11</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field11"
                        name="field11"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 12</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field12"
                        name="field12"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <ControlLabel>Field 13</ControlLabel>
                      <FormControl
                        id="field13"
                        name="field13"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                      />
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                  <td />
                  <td>
                    <FormGroup>
                      <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit">
                        Search{' '}
                      </Button>
                      {'  '}
                      <Button bsStyle="primary" type="reset">
                        Clear{' '}
                      </Button>
                    </FormGroup>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <div className="row ng-scope">
                <div className="col-lg-15">
                  <Panel header={<span>Search Results</span>}>
                    <div
                      id="dataTables-example_filter"
                      className="dataTables_filter"
                    >
                      <label htmlFor={'search'}>
                        Search:
                        <input
                          type="search"
                          className="form-control input-sm"
                          placeholder=""
                          aria-controls="dataTables-example"
                          id="search"
                          onKeyUp={this.searchFunction}
                        />
                      </label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="table-responsive">
                      <table
                        id="Search-Table"
                        className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                      >
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th className="sorting_asc" onClick={this.onSort('Field 1','asc')} aria-sort="ascending"
                         aria-label="Field1 :activate to sort column descending"
                         aria-controls="dataTables-example" 
                         rowSpan="1"
                         colSpan="1"
                         tabIndex="0">Field 1
                         <span className={this.setArrow('Field 1')}></span>
                         </th>
                            <th>Field 2</th>
                            <th>Field 3</th>
                            <th>Field 4</th>
                            <th>Field 5</th>
                            <th>Field 6</th>
                            <th>Field 7</th>
                            <th>Field 8</th>
                            <th>Field 9</th>
                            <th>Field 10</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                          {this.state.respData.map((item, i) => {
                            return (
                              <tr key={i}>
                                <td> {item.Field1}</td>
                                <td> {item.Field2}</td>
                                <td> {item.Field3}</td>
                                <td> {item.Field4}</td>
                                <td> {item.Field5}</td>
                                <td> {item.Field6}</td>
                                <td> {item.Field7}</td>
                                <td> {item.Field8}</td>
                                <td> {item.Field9}</td>
                                <td> {item.Field10}</td>
                              </tr>
                            );
                          })}
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </Panel>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Here is the correct answer :

```
myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, td1, i;
        input = document.getElementById("search");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        console.log('input in searchFunction:',input);
        console.log('filter in searchFunction:',filter);
        table = document.getElementById("Search-Table");
        console.log('table in searchFunction:',table);
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var innertext = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").innertext;
        console.log("innertext :",innertext);
        console.log('tr in searchFunction:',tr);
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
          td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
          console.log('td in for before if:',td);
          if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
              tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
          }       

        }
    }
```

Comment: At first glance, is `myFunction()` your search function? since there doesn't seem to be any `this.searchFunction`. That may be part of your problem. Also, I'm guessing you should be searching in the response data in state rather than the dom.

Comment: Hi Ted , Thanks for the inputs , I did add this in the constructor     this.myFunction= this.myFunction.bind(this); Yet the problem is the same , Could you please elaborate on this ? How do I search in response data rather than the dom ? This is where the respData is stored . If you could shed more light on this , that would be very helpful

Comment: This is where response data is stored : this.setState({ respData:response_jsonObj});  this is how it is rendered in grid format :

Comment: {this.state.respData.map((item, i) => {
                        return (
                          <tr key={i}>
                            <td> {item.Field1}</td>
                            <td> {item.Field2}</td>
                            <td> {item.Field3}</td>
                            <td> {item.Field4}</td>
                            <td> {item.Field5}</td>
                            <td> {item.Field6}</td>
                          </tr>
                        );
                      })}

Comment: You should filter, order or limit your data in your server using your api request. If it is done using a post request, you should send the data so that in the server you know what to do and then get the results that are already ordered. You should not order in the dom. Also you should not access the dom with `getElementById`. React is a Dom library and you should use it for what it's for. Have a read at the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) to see how to get dom elements, how to store or get data using the state, and basically how to use React in general.

Comment: Thanks , will do , I figured what you were pointing at , In the search function that I have emulated from an existing online javascript code snippet , it is searching by tagname of tr html tag when console log the output it is just displaying trs in a row and a stream , here is the code snippet I tried out : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

Comment: @c-chavez I am getting the data displayed in the tabular format correctly , I just need to have a searvh filter above the table where in I can search for a particular entry in that table and that gets displayed in the table

Comment: @Ice_Queen the problem with this comes when your result has a lot of items. If it is only a small size table for example for 10 items you can do it in the dom, but if you are searching inside a db that has hundreds of rows you will want to filter, limit and order your results in the server before you send them to the client. If you don't, you will show wrong results (filtering only the ones shown, but there could be more in the db). Same with ordering.

Comment: @Ice_Queen did you have any luck following my suggestions? if you still need some help you can add the code that you've tried and I can have a look and guide you in the right way. Let me know!

Comment: @c-chavez I have made modifications to the above snippet in search function by the name of myfunction , My sorting on individual column is working fine but the search criteria when I type the search text which is a string is not able to retrieve records pertaining to the search criteria , and the search data which is supposed to store the searched data and reassigned to respdata to render is not doing the job , I get the error in the console as : Uncaught ReferenceError: searchData is not defined
    at eval

Comment: @SergioMoura Is it possible for you to provide your inputs on this please ?

Comment: @Ice_Queen sorry, I think you forgot to add the `myFunction` function (I only see the bind). Also, would it be possible to get a sample data `this.state.respData`? I also see some uses of variables in the state but you don't seem to initialise them in the constructor. Please initialise them in the constructor, with a default (or empty) value. For example, in `setArrow` you are getting `this.state.sort.column` but in the first render `this.state.sort` is undefined, so `this.state.sort.column` throws an error for me.

Comment: @c-chavez I fixed it , the search is working fine , Thanks for your inputs , I used the DOM method itself and it worked out fine, Thanks . :-)

Comment: @Ice_Queen nice! Please add your answer and mark it as the correct answer for this post so anyone else can benefit from your input. Cheers!

Comment: @c-chavez Here it is : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp , I had posted it here before too .

Comment: @Ice_Queen yes, but if you post your code (the parts that you changed to make it work) as an answer, you can find the answer faster, and specifically for your case, since that tutorial is a general case.

Comment: @c-chavez Have posted the same

Comment: @c-chavez Could you please provide your inputs for this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936112/react-js-need-to-split-the-state-object-being-retrieved , I have another issue where I am hitting another API in a different function and I want to render the data from there , I am able to retrieve the response from API in JSON Format , I am unable to render it , The code for rendering the data is in getDetails method , Please provide your inouts regarding the same