# React JS : Need to split the state object being retrieved

Tags: reactjs, split

I have a handle click function which is invoked when we click on the rows and the id from that row is being passed onto the handleClick function which has the ID being retrieved from there to pass it onto the API . But is of this format 
{stdID : "02468"} and I need to split this and just pass the numerical part which is 02468 . I used the split function but I get the error split is not a function I just need the value part of the state object being retrieved and pass it onto the API to retrieve the records and links or travels to another page.
I have checked out various existing Stackoverflow posts and tried to replicate the same but to no avail. Please provide your inputs

```
import React, { PropTypes , Component } from 'react';
import {
    Panel,
    Button,
    PageHeader,
    ControlLabel,
    FormControl,
    Pagination,
    Form,
import StatWidget from '../../src/components/Widget';
var alignment = {
  marginLeft: "550px",
  marginbottom: "100px"
}

class displayDetails extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

      };



    render() {
        console.log('Child Component C Summary:',this.props.respData);
        console.log('Child Component E Summary:',this.props.EData);
        console.log('Child Component A Summary:',this.props.addData);
        console.log('Child Component P Summary:',this.props.PData);



        if(this.props.addData === undefined){
          this.props.addData.FIELD 1="NA";
          this.props.addData.FIELD 2="NA";
          this.props.addData.FIELD 3="NA";
          this.props.addData.FIELD 4="NA";
          this.props.addData.FIELD 5="NA";


        }

        if(this.props.PData === undefined){
          this.props.PData.FIELD 1="NA";
          this.props.PData.FIELD 2="NA";
          this.props.PData.FIELD 3="NA";


        }

        if(this.props.EData === undefined){
          this.props.EData.FIELD 1="NA";
          this.props.EData.FIELD 2="NA";
          this.props.EData.FIELD 3="NA";
          this.props.EData.FIELD 4="NA";
          this.props.EData.FIELD 5="NA";

        }

        return (
         <div> 
          <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <StatWidget
            style="panel-primary"
            icon="fa fa-dollar fa-5x"
            count={this.props.respData.LIFE_TIME_SPEND}
            headerText="Life Time Spend"
            footerText="View Details"
            linkTo="/blank"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <StatWidget
            style="panel-green"
            icon="fa fa-phone   fa-5x"
            count={this.props.respData.BEST_HOME_PHONE}
            headerText="Best Home Phone"
            footerText="View Details"
            linkTo="/"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <StatWidget
            style="panel-yellow"
            icon="fa fa-home fa-5x"
            count={this.props.respData.RESIDENCE_COUNTRY}
            headerText="Country"
            footerText="View Details"
            linkTo="/"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
          <StatWidget
            style="panel-red"
            icon="fa fa-shopping-bag fa-5x"
            count={this.props.respData.BRAND_CODE}
            headerText="Brand"
            footerText="View Details"
            linkTo="/"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <tr>
            <td><h1>{this.props.respData.FIELD 1} {this.props.respData.FIELD 2}</h1></td>
            </tr>
        </div>

            <div className="col-lg-15">
            <Panel header={<span>Customer Profile Data </span>} >
              <div className="table-responsive">
                <table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th> FIELD 1 </th>
                  <th> FIELD 2 </th>
                  <th> FIELD 3 </th>
                  <th> FIELD 4 </th>
                  <th> FIELD 5 </th>
                  <th> FIELD 6 </th>
                  <th> FIELD 7 </th>
                  <th> FIELD 8</th>
                  <th> FIELD 9</th>
                  <th> FIELD 10</th>
                  <th> FIELD 11</th>
                  <th> FIELD 12</th>
                  <th> FIELD 13</th>
                  <th> FIELD 14</th>
                  <th> FIELD 15</th>
                  <th> FIELD 16</th>
                  <th> FIELD 17</th>
                  </tr>
             </thead>     
             <tbody>
             <tr>
             <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 1}</td>  
             <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 2}</td>
             <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 3}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 4}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 5}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 6}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 7}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 8}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 9}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 10}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 11}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 12}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 13}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 14}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 15}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 16}</td>
              <td>{this.props.respData.FIELD 17}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>  
          </table>
           </div>
           </Panel>



          <div className="col-lg-6">
            <Panel header={<span>Phone </span>} >
              <div className="table-responsive">
                <table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>FIELD 1</th>
                      <th>FIELD 2 </th>
                      <th>FIELD 3 </th>
                      <th>FIELD 4 </th>
                      <th>FIELD 5 </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
             {this.props.PData.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <tr key={i}>  
                        <td> {item.FIELD 1}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 2}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 3}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 4}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 5}</td>
             </tr>
);
        })}
            </tbody>
            </table>
              </div>
            </Panel>
          </div>

<div className="col-lg-6">
<Panel header={<span> Email </span>} >
<div className="table-responsive">
  <table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>FIELD 1  </th>
        <th>FIELD 2</th>
        <th>FIELD 3</th>
        <th>FIELD 4</th>
        <th>FIELD 15</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {this.props.EData.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <tr key={i}>  
                 <td> {item.FIELD 1}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 2}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 3}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 4}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 5}</td>
             </tr>
);
        })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</Panel>
</div>

<div className="col-lg-6">
<Panel header={<span>Address </span>} >
<div className="table-responsive">
  <table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> FIELD 1 </th>
        <th> FIELD 2 </th>
        <th> FIELD 3 </th>
        <th> FIELD 4 </th>
        <th> FIELD 5 </th>
        <th> FIELD 6 </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {this.props.addData .map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <tr key={i}>  
                 <td> {item.FIELD 1}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 2}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 3}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 4}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 5}</td>
                 <td> {item.FIELD 6}</td>
             </tr>
);
        })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</Panel>
</div>   
<div className="col-lg-6">
<Form>
<FormGroup controlId="formControlsDisabledButton" style={alignment}>
<Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit" disabled>Save</Button>
{'  '}
<Button bsStyle="primary" type="reset" disabled>Cancel</Button>
</FormGroup>
 </Form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

        )
      }
}


export default displayDetails;
```

Comment: Pass `item.Field1` instead of `{stdID:item.Field1}` to `handleClick`

Comment: @wdm Thanks that resolved the issue , the next step is when I click on it I need for it to travel to another page and display just that Id related record's information . I already have a render which displays the results in a tabular format but I want the data related just to that record to be displayed on another page or the next page

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the `respData` from the `fetch` call in `handleClick` to be used in another component? If so, which component and where is it rendered?

Comment: @wdm Thanks for the quick response , Yes I am new to react , So I currently have only one component and since I had only API call before I would render in the same component , Now I have another function invoking another API for which I would like to display results pertaining to that ID in another page . What is the best approach to that ? I researched quite a few things and some say Link and so forth, Right now I am able to get the JSON response and store it in respData

Comment: If you're using `this.state.respData` in your `render()` method then updating `this.state.respData` with new data it should automatically trigger a re-render.

Comment: @wdm That doesn't seem to be happening , I tried all of the combinations , How do I render it in a different component , Because over here we already have form and result grid , My purpose is to click on the row of result grid and link to another page with detailed information displayed regarding that record

Comment: Passing data through components depends on their relation to one another. It's easy to pass data to a child component as a prop such as `<CustomerList customers={this.state.customers}/>` however passing data from a child to parent or to sibling components requires a function be passed down from parent to child where the child will run the function to update the parent's state. A sibling would be aware of the parent's state change if it's receiving the value as a prop. See docs for some examples: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @wdm Thanks for the docs I did go through the documentation , I am under a time crunch and this is blocking my task , I have built another component display details,  just to get the rendered sent by the displayBlank component, In handleclick I have the json response assigned to the state object respData from here I want to pass it onto a child component by the name display details, I tried history.push and it didn't work , Can you please provide me the code snippet to pass the state object to a child component and have it rendered there ? Thanks

Comment: If `DisplayDetails` is rendered as a child of `displayBlank` then you can pass `respData` as a prop like this: `<DisplayDetails respData={this.state.respData}/>` and then in the `DisplayDetails` component you can access this data through `this.props.respData`

Comment: @wdm Thanks for the inputs , I tried and I am able to get what is being rendered in child component that is a simple text stating hello world, That happens when I give <DisplayDetails respData={this.state.respData}/>  after tr onclick in the displayblank component, but I am unable to render the respData , I get the error field on undefined and displays the errors on a redpage moreover the hello world is being displayed along with the search results in the page , Please suggest how can I get the respData to be rendered in displayDetails , I have attached the code for the same

Comment: Can you try to `console.log(this.props.respData)` before `return <h1>Hello World!</h1>` and see what shows up in the browser console?

Comment: I am unable to understand why respData is coming up as undefined . when I do this.props.respData in child component , I have attached the entire code , Please tell me how can I get this fixed

Comment: @wdm Thanks for the quick response , So first time before search results are displayed and only a skeleton form and search results table along with Hello World when I click on the row once search results are displayed that time I see in console.log the respData in JSON format.

Comment: So when you click on the row, the data is fetched, state is set with `respData` and your child component receives it. Sounds like it's working to me. Is there another issue?

Comment: I am not able to render the respData in a tabular format :  class displayDetails extends Component {


 render() {
     console.log('Child Component:',this.props.respData);
     return(

        <tr>
         <td>
             {this.props.respData.field1}
           </td>  
<td>
             {this.props.respData.field2}
           </td>  
<td>
             {this.props.respData.field3}
           </td>  
            </tr>
  
     )
         

  }

}

Comment: It is displaying in console but not in the page in a row column type. Please provide your inputs

Comment: Look at this code sandbox. I've tried to replicate a simplified version of the issue. Let me know if it helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/6jqp3loqnn

Comment: Thanks a lot , but then again this is getting displayed on the same page I want this to be displayed on another page not on the same page , How do I do that ?

Comment: I've updated the sandbox to show routing. Note the URL path changing in the sandbox address bar. https://codesandbox.io/s/6jqp3loqnn This is an example of passing data to a parent and then back down to a different child.

Comment: @wdm Thank you , that works, is there a way I can conditionally render this , Initially just the forms and search results table and when I click on the row just the result pertaining to that record is displayed and not along with form components , Thanks again . I am referring tothis currently : https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html, Is there a way to incorporate this in my code ?

Comment: @wdm Thank you , this has been resolved

Comment: @wdm Thanks for the inputs , I had one more query , I have back button incorporated in Display Details and on doing onpress on that back button it should take me to the previous page with form and search results. I tried it with link it didn't work , I tried a few others on stackoverflow didn't work , Can you please provide your inputs ?

Comment: Updated this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/6jqp3loqnn -- I've added two methods to the `DisplayDetails` component showing how to programmatically route. You can test both with the button's `onClick` handler. Also, I've added a `<Link/>` to show how that works. Notice I've added `routerProps` to the route in order to pass the `history` object into the component.

Comment: @wdm I have updated my code snippet and just put the code for display details so some of the state objects being passed from parent to child components can be undefined at times hence it used to throw undefined error while rendering the data , I gave the condition to check when those are undefined to have individual fields to be set to either empty string or NA and inspite of that it throws error saying cannot set property of field1 for undefined , how do I resolve this ? Please provide your inputs

Comment: You can't set a key on `undefined`. It's like saying `undefined.foo = "bar"`. Try this `const addData = this.props.addData || {}` for each prop you need to check. If it's `undefined` it'll set it to an empty object for which you can define keys.

Comment: @wdm Thanks , I tried that now and empty object is assigned to it when I console.log I get this , {} , but when I do a {addData.map((item, i) => {return ( <tr key={i}>  <td> {item.field1}</td>);})} I get adddata.map is not a function error. Condition given is : addData = this.props.addData === undefined ? {} : this.props.addData ;

Comment: Try `Object.entries(addData).map(...` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: @wdm Thanks for your inputs through out this , I had to use object.keys(addData).map and use addData[item].field 1 , it worked , Thanks again , I have posted the code too.

Comment: @wdm I am stuck in another issue and have posted the query here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173512/react-js-need-to-replicate-the-code-for-different-tables-and-getting-undefined/53174697?noredirect=1#comment93244325_53174697 , Could you please provide your inputs ? I am trying to access the child component's state object from parent , Tried various ways with callback and so forth , Haven't been successful with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   import React, { PropTypes , Component } from 'react';
    import './blank.css';
    import {
      Panel,
      Button,
      PageHeader,
      ControlLabel,
      FormControl,
      Pagination,
      FormGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';
    import JwPagination from 'jw-react-pagination';
    import FormControlFeedback from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControlFeedback';
    import FormControlStatic from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControlStatic';
    import InputGroupAddon from 'react-bootstrap/lib/InputGroupAddon';
    import {Link, BrowserRouter as Router,Route} from 'react-router-dom'; 

    const customStyles = {
      ul: {
          backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      li: {
          border: '1px solid green'
      },
      a: {
          color: 'blue'
      }
    };
    const title = 'Customer-LookUp';
    const spacing = {
      marginRight: "20px",
      marginbottom: "20px"
    }
    const buttonalignment = {
      marginLeft: "81px",
      marginbottom: "20px"
    }

    class displayBlank extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
              newData: [],
              pageOfItems: [],
              respData:[],
              sort: {
                column: null,
                direction: 'desc',
              }
          };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.searchFunction = this.searchFunction.bind(this);
        this.setArrow = this.setArrow.bind(this);
        this.onSort = this.onSort.bind(this);
        this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      };

      onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
        // update local state with new page of items
        this.setState({pageOfItems});
    }
      handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const form = event.target;
        const data = new FormData(form);
        const arrayValue = [];
        var i = 0;
        console.log('Data from Form:',data);
        for (let name of data.keys()) {
          const input = form.elements[name];
          const parserName = input.dataset.parse;
          const parsedValue = data.get(name);
          console.log('name',name);
          console.log('parsedValue',parsedValue);
          if (typeof(parsedValue) == 'undefined' || parsedValue == null) {
             console.log('Not Defined or Not Null')
             arrayValue[i] = "";
             data.set(name, arrayValue[i]);
      }
      else{
        data.set(name, parsedValue);
        arrayValue[i] = parsedValue;
      }
          i=i+1;
        }
    console.log('brandname:after get',arrayValue[0]);
    console.log('LastName:after get',arrayValue[2]);
    console.log('zipcode:after get',arrayValue[8]);
    var response_data = "";
    var response_jsonObj ;
    var txt = "";
    var req = {"CustomerLookupRequest" : [{
    "Field1":arrayValue[0],
    "Field2": arrayValue[1],
    "Field3":arrayValue[2],
    "Field4":arrayValue[3],
    "Field5":arrayValue[4],
    "Field6":arrayValue[5],
    "Field7":arrayValue[6],
    "Field8":arrayValue[7],
    "Field9":arrayValue[8],
    "Field10":arrayValue[9]
      }]
    };
    console.log('req string :' + req);
        fetch('API_URL', {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, application/xml,  */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
          },
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(req)}
        ).then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
              console.log('Problem in fetching');
              return;
            }
            response.text().then(data => {
              console.log('Data in Console',data);
              response_data = data;
              console.log('Response Data',response_data);
              response_jsonObj = JSON.parse(response_data);
              console.log('Response JSON Object',response_jsonObj);
                this.setState({ newData:response_jsonObj});
                //console.log('customer Data in handle submit',customerData);
            });
          }).catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
          }

          handleClick(field1,field2){

            var ID = field1;
            var Name = field2;
            var newresponse_jsonObj,response_data;
            var req ={"GetCustomerRequest": [{
              "field1": field2,
              "field2": "xyz",
              "field3": field1,
              "field4": "",
              "field5": "",
              "field6": ""
              }]
              };
              fetch('API_URL', {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, application/xml,  */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
          },
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(req)}
        ).then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
              console.log('Problem in fetching');
              return;
            }
            response.text().then(data => {
              response_data = data;
              //console.log('Response Data in Handle Click for Get-Customer',response_data);
              newresponse_jsonObj = JSON.parse(response_data);
              console.log('Response JSON Object for Get-Customer',newresponse_jsonObj);
                this.setState({respData:newresponse_jsonObj});
                this.setState({ pageOfItems:newresponse_jsonObj});
                this.getDetails();

            });
          }).catch(error => this.setState({ error }));

          }

          getDetails(){



              console.log('Get Customer Method:');
            <table>
            <tbody>
                 {this.state.pageOfItems.map((item, i) => {
              return (
                 <tr key={i} >
                     <td >{item.XYZ.Field1}</td>
                     <td> {item.XYZ.Field2}</td>
                     <td> {item.XYZ.Field3}</td>
                     <td> {item.XYZ.Field4}</td>
                     <td> {item.Field5}</td>
                 </tr>
              );
            })}
                </tbody>
                  </table>






          }

          searchFunction() {
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, td1, i;
            input = document.getElementById("search");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            console.log('input in searchFunction:',input);
            console.log('filter in searchFunction:',filter);
            table = document.getElementById("Search-Table");
            console.log('table in searchFunction:',table);
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            var innertext = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").innertext;
            console.log("innertext :",innertext);
            console.log('tr in searchFunction:',tr);
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
              td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
              console.log('td in for before if:',td);
              if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                  tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                  tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
              }       

            }
        } 


          onSort = (column) => (e) => {
            const direction = this.state.sort.column ? (this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc') : 'desc';
            console.log('direction',direction);
            console.log('column',column);
            const sortedData = this.state.pageOfItems.sort((a, b) => {
              if (column === 'Field1') {
                return a.Field1.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.Field1.toUpperCase());
              }

              else if (column === 'Last Name') {
                return 

a.Field1.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.Field1.toUpperCase());
                  }

                });


                if (direction === 'desc') {
                  sortedData.reverse();
                }

                this.setState({
                  pageOfItems: sortedData,
                  sort: {
                      direction,
                        column,
            }
                });
              };

              setArrow = (column,className) => {
                let current_className = className;

                if (this.state.sort.column === column) {
                  current_className += this.state.sort.direction === 'asc' ? ' asc' : ' desc';
                }

                console.log(current_className);

                return current_className;
              };  

          render() {

            var {custID} = this.state;
            return (
              <div id = "id1">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-12">
              <PageHeader>Title of The Page </PageHeader>
              </div>
              </div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <table>
            <tr>
              <td>  
              <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>Field1</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl componentClass="select" id="brand"  name="brand" placeholder="select">
                <option value="Value1">Value1</option>
                <option value="Value2">Value2</option>
                <option value="Value3">Value3</option>
                </FormControl>
              </FormGroup>
              </td> 
              <td>
              <FormGroup  style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>Field2</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  id="customerId"  name="customerId"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Text"
                />
              </FormGroup>
              </td>
              <td>
              <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>Field3</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  style={spacing}
                  id="lastname"  name="lastname"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Text"
                />
              </FormGroup>
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>  
              <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>Field4</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  id="firstName"  name="firstName"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Text"
                />
              </FormGroup>
              </td>
              <td>
              <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>Field5</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  id="housenumber"  name="housenumber"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Text"
                />
              </FormGroup>
              </td>
              <td>
              <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>Field6</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  id="addressline"  name="addressline"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Text"
                />
              </FormGroup>
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>
              <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>Field7</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  id="zipcode"  name="zipcode"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Text"
                />
              </FormGroup>
              </td>
              <td>
              <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>Field8</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  id="email"  name="email"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Text"
                />
              </FormGroup>
              </td>
              <td>
              <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>Field9</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  id="phonenumber"  name="phonenumber"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Text"
                />
              </FormGroup>
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>  
              <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                <ControlLabel>Field10</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  id="last4digitsphone"  name="last4digitsphone"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Text"
                />
              </FormGroup>
              </td>
              <td></td>
              <td>
              <FormGroup style={buttonalignment}>
                <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit">Search </Button>
                {'  '}
                <Button bsStyle="primary" type="reset">Clear </Button>
              </FormGroup>
              </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

              <div className="row ng-scope">
                <div className="col-lg-15">
                  <Panel header={<span> Search Results</span>} >
                  <div id="dataTables-example_filter" className="dataTables_filter">
                             <label htmlFor={'search'}>Search:
                               <input
                                 type="text"
                                 className="form-control input-sm"
                                 placeholder=""
                                 aria-controls="dataTables-example"
                                 id="search" onKeyUp={this.searchFunction}
                               />
                             </label>
                           </div><br></br>
                  <div id ="Search-Table" className="table-responsive">
                    <table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" id="dataTables-example"  role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTables-example_info">
                    <thead>
                           <tr role="row">
                             <th>Field1</th>
                             <th>Field2</th>
                             <th className="sorting" onClick={this.onSort('Field 3','asc')} aria-sort="ascending"
                            aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending"
                            aria-controls="dataTables-example"
                            rowSpan="1"
                            colSpan="1"
                            tabIndex="0">Field3<span className={this.setArrow('First Name')}></span></th>
                             <th className="sorting" onClick={this.onSort('Field 4','asc')}>Last Name <span className={this.setArrow('Field 4')}></span></th>
                             <th>Field3</th>
                             <th>Field4</th>
                             <th>Field5</th>
                             <th>Field6</th>
                             <th>Field7</th>
                             <th>Field8</th>
                             <th>Field9</th>
                          </tr>
                         </thead>
                     <tbody>
                     {this.state.pageOfItems.map((item, i) => {
                  return (
                     <tr key={i} onClick={()=>this.handleClick(item.Field1,item.Field2)}>
                         <td >{item.Field1}</td>
                         <td> {item.Field2}</td>
                         <td> {item.Field3}</td>
                         <td> {item.Field4}</td>
                         <td> {item.Field5}</td>
                         <td> {item.Field6}</td>
                         <td> {item.Field7}</td>
                         <td> {item.Field8}</td>
                         <td> {item.Field9}</td>
                         <td> {item.Field10}</td>
                         <td> {item.Field11}</td>
                     </tr>
        );
                })}
                    </tbody>
                      </table>
                      <div className="col-sm-6 pullRight " >
                      <JwPagination  items={this.state.newData} onChangePage={this.onChangePage} /> 
                      </div>   
                      </div>
                      </Panel>
                      </div>
                      </div>
              </form>
    <DisplayDetails respData={this.state.respData}/>
        </div>

        );
         }
          }
        export default displayBlank;

    DisplayDetails.js

    import React, { PropTypes , Component } from 'react';


    class displayDetails extends Component {


     render() {
       return <h1 >Hello World!</h1>
       {this.props.respData.map((item, i) => {
        return (
           <tr key={i} >

               <td >{item.FIELD1}</td>
               <td> {item.FIELD2}</td>
           </tr>
    );
      })}

<div className="col-lg-6">
<Panel header={<span>add</span>} >
<div className="table-responsive">
  <table className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th> FIELD 1 </th>
        <th> FIELD 2 </th>
        <th> FIELD 3 </th>
        <th> FIELD 4</th>
        <th> FIELD 5 </th>
        <th> FIELD 6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {Object.keys(addData).map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <tr key={i}>  
                          <td> {addData[item].FIELD1}</td>
                 <td> {addData[item].FIELD2}</td>
                 <td> {addData[item].FIELD3}</td>
                 <td> {addData[item].FIELD4}</td>
                 <td> {addData[item].FIELD5}</td>
                 <td> {addData[item].FIELD6}</td>
             </tr>
);
        })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</Panel>
</div>

      }

    }


    export default displayDetails;
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
const stateObj = { stdID: "02468" }

const values = Object.values(stateObj)

// values -> ["02468"]
```

Comment: Thanks , But wdm's suggestion worked and all I needed to do was just pass that column's information rather than assigning it to a state object

Comment: Yes, his suggestion should work for your needs... but in general you can’t do .split on an object... that’s a method for arrays... Object.keys will get you the keys and Object.values the values of the object...

Comment: Could you please guide me on rendering the data , rightnow only the last field related to the record is getting displayed , I need to have the detailed information related to the record and also on a different page

Comment: I have updated the post with the latest code , I need your help in rendering the data obtained from handleClick function's json response object