# React JS : Need to replicate the code for different tables and getting undefined exception when I do that

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to replicate the code for other tables with add and remove option but getting not defined exception on map when I do that . The code I have referred to is over [here][1]. I tried a few things for replicating the same but it didn't yield anything.I am not able to edit the rows . How do I fix it ?

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import {
      Panel,
      Button,
      Col,
      PageHeader,
      ControlLabel,
      FormControl,
      HelpBlock,
      FormGroup,
      Checkbox,
      Form,
      Radio,
      InputGroup,
      Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';

    import FormControlFeedback from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControlFeedback';
    import FormControlStatic from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControlStatic';
    import InputGroupAddon from 'react-bootstrap/lib/InputGroupAddon';
    import Email from './Email';
    import Phone from './Phone';

    const spacing = {
      marginRight: "20px",
      marginbottom: "20px"
    }
    const buttonalignment = {
      marginLeft: "81px",
      marginbottom: "20px"
    }




    class displayForms extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        //  this.state.products = [];
        this.state = {};
        this.state.filterText = "";
        this.state.products = [
          {
            id: 1,
          Field1: "",
           Field2: '',
           Field3: '',
           Field4: '',
           Field5:'',
           Field6: '',
           Field7: ''
          }
        ];

      }
      handleUserInput(filterText) {
        this.setState({filterText: filterText});
      };
      handleRowDel(product) {
        var index = this.state.products.indexOf(product);
        this.state.products.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState(this.state.products);
      };

      handleAddEvent(evt) {
        var id = (+ new Date() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)).toString(36);
        var product = {
          id: id,
          Field1: "",
           Field2: '',
           Field13: '',
           Field14: '',
           Field5:'',
           Field6: '',
           Field7: ''

        }
        this.state.products.push(product);
        this.setState(this.state.products);

      }

      handleProductTable(evt) {
        var item = {
          id: evt.target.id,
          name: evt.target.name,
          value: evt.target.value
        };
        console.log('item.value[0] in address',item.value);
        console.log('item.value[1] in address',item.value);
        console.log('item.value[2] in address',item.value);
    var products = this.state.products.slice();
      var newProducts = products.map(function(product) {

        for (var key in product) {
          if (key == item.name && product.id == item.id) {
            product[key] = item.value;

          }
        }
        return product;
      });
        this.setState({products:newProducts});
      //  console.log(this.state.products);
      };
      render() {

        return (
          <div>

            <ProductTable onProductTableUpdate={this.handleProductTable.bind(this)} onRowAdd={this.handleAddEvent.bind(this)} onRowDel={this.handleRowDel.bind(this)} products={this.state.products} filterText={this.state.filterText}/>
            <Email />
            <Phone />
          </div>
        );

      }

    }


    class ProductTable extends React.Component {

      render() {
        var onProductTableUpdate = this.props.onProductTableUpdate;
        var rowDel = this.props.onRowDel;
        var filterText = this.props.filterText;
        var product = this.props.products.map(function(product) {
          if (product.Address_Line.indexOf(filterText) === -1) {
            return;
          }
          return (<ProductRow onProductTableUpdate={onProductTableUpdate} product={product} onDelEvent={rowDel.bind(this)} key={product.id}/>)
        });
        return (

          <div id="test">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-12">
                    <PageHeader>Test App</PageHeader>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                          <ControlLabel>ID</ControlLabel>
                          <FormControl
                            id="field1" name="field1"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Enter Text"
                          />
                        </FormGroup>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <td>
                      <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                          <ControlLabel> Month</ControlLabel>
                          <FormControl componentClass="select" id="MM" name="MM" placeholder="select">
                            <option value="01">01</option>
                            <option value="02">02</option>
                            <option value="03">03</option>
                            <option value="04">04</option>
                            <option value="05">05</option>
                            <option value="06">06</option>
                            <option value="07">07</option>
                            <option value="08">08</option>
                            <option value="09">09</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                          </FormControl>
                        </FormGroup>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <FormGroup style={spacing}>
                          <ControlLabel> Day</ControlLabel>
                          <FormControl componentClass="select" id="DD" name="DD" placeholder="select">
                            <option value="01">01</option>
                            <option value="02">02</option>
                            <option value="03">03</option>
                            <option value="04">04</option>
                            <option value="05">05</option>
                            <option value="06">06</option>
                            <option value="07">07</option>
                            <option value="08">08</option>
                            <option value="09">09</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                            <option value="13">13</option>
                            <option value="14">14</option>
                            <option value="15">15</option>
                            <option value="16">16</option>
                            <option value="17">17</option>
                            <option value="18">18</option>
                            <option value="19">19</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="21">21</option>
                            <option value="22">22</option>
                            <option value="23">23</option>
                            <option value="24">24</option>
                            <option value="25">25</option>
                            <option value="26">26</option>
                            <option value="27">27</option>
                            <option value="28">28</option>
                            <option value="29">29</option>
                            <option value="30">30</option>
                            <option value="31">31</option>
                          </FormControl>
                        </FormGroup>
                      </td>
                  </table>
                  </form>
          <div className="col-lg-15">
          <th>Address</th>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.props.onRowAdd} className="btn btn-success pull-right">+</button>
            <table className="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Field1</th>
                  <th>Field2</th>
                  <th>Field3</th>
                  <th>field4</th>
                  <th>field5</th>
                  <th>field6</th>
                  <th>field7</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                {product}

              </tbody>

            </table>
          </div>
          </div>
        );

      }

    }

    class ProductRow extends React.Component {
      onDelEvent() {
        this.props.onDelEvent(this.props.product);

      }
      render() {

        return (
          <tr className="eachRow">
            <EditableCell onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              "type": "Field1",
              value: this.props.product.Field1,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/>
            <EditableCell onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              type: "Field2",
              value: this.props.product.Field2,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/>
            <EditableCell onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              type: "Field3",
              value: this.props.product.Field3,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/>
            <EditableCell onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              type: "Field4",
              value: this.props.product.Field4,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/>
             <EditableCell onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              type: "Field5",
              value: this.props.product.Field5,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/>
            <EditableCell onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              type: "Field6",
              value: this.props.product.Field6,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/>
            <EditableCell onProductTableUpdate={this.props.onProductTableUpdate} cellData={{
              type: "Field7",
              value: this.props.product.Field7,
              id: this.props.product.id
            }}/>
            <td className="del-cell">
              <input type="button" onClick={this.onDelEvent.bind(this)} value="REMOVE" className="del-btn"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );

      }

    }
    class EditableCell extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <td>
            <input type='text' name={this.props.cellData.type} id={this.props.cellData.id} value={this.props.cellData.value} onChange={this.props.onProductTableUpdate}/>
          </td>
        );

      }

    }


    displayForms.contextTypes = { setTitle: PropTypes.func.isRequired };

    export default displayForms;

//import React, { PropTypes , Component } from 'react';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  Panel,
  Button,
  Col,
  PageHeader,
  ControlLabel,
  FormControl,
  HelpBlock,
  FormGroup,
  Checkbox,
  Form,
  Radio,
  InputGroup,
  Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';

import FormControlFeedback from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControlFeedback';
import FormControlStatic from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControlStatic';
import InputGroupAddon from 'react-bootstrap/lib/InputGroupAddon';





class Phone extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //  this.state.phones = [];
    this.state = {};
    this.state.filterText = "";
    this.state.phones = [
      {
        id: 1,
       Field1: '',
       Field2: '',
       Field3: '',
       Field4: '',
       Field5: ''
      }
    ];

  }
  handleUserInput(filterText) {
    this.setState({filterText: filterText});
  };
  handleRowDel(phone) {
    var index = this.state.phones.indexOf(phone);
    this.state.phones.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState(this.state.phones);
  };

  handleAddEvent(evt) {
    var id = (+ new Date() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)).toString(36);
    var phone = {
      id: id,
      Phone_Number: '',
       Type: '',
       Receive_Calls: '',
       Receive_Texts: '',
       Preferred_Phone_Number: ''

    }
    this.state.phones.push(phone);
    this.setState(this.state.phones);

  }

  handlephoneTable(evt) {
    var item = {
      id: evt.target.id,
      name: evt.target.name,
      value: evt.target.value
    };
    console.log('item.value in phone',item.value);
var phones = this.state.phones.slice();
  var newphones = phones.map(function(phone) {

    for (var key in phone) {
      if (key == item.name && phone.id == item.id) {
        phone[key] = item.value;

      }
    }
    return phone;
  });
    this.setState({phones:newphones});
  //  console.log(this.state.phones);
  };
  render() {

    return (
      <div>

        <PhoneTable onphoneTableUpdate={this.handlephoneTable.bind(this)} onRowAdd={this.handleAddEvent.bind(this)} onRowDel={this.handleRowDel.bind(this)} phones={this.state.phones} filterText={this.state.filterText}/>
      </div>
    );

  }

}


class PhoneTable extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var onphoneTableUpdate = this.props.onphoneTableUpdate;
    var rowDel = this.props.onRowDel;
    var filterText = this.props.filterText;
    var phone = this.props.phones.map(function(phone) {
      if (phone.Type.indexOf(filterText) === -1) {
        return;
      }
      return (<PhoneRow onphoneTableUpdate={onphoneTableUpdate} phone={phone} onDelEvent={rowDel.bind(this)} key={phone.id}/>)
    });
    return (
      <div>

    <th>Phone</th>
      <button type="button" onClick={this.props.onRowAdd} className="btn btn-success pull-right">Add</button>
        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Phone_Number</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Receive_Calls</th>
              <th>Receive_Texts</th>
              <th>Preferred_Phone_Number</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {phone}

          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
    );

  }

}

class PhoneRow extends React.Component {
  onDelEvent() {
    this.props.onDelEvent(this.props.phone);

  }
  render() {

    return (
      <tr className="eachRow">
        <EditableCell onphoneTableUpdate={this.props.onphoneTableUpdate} cellData={{
          "type": "Field1",
          value: this.props.phone.Field1,
          id: this.props.phone.id
        }}/>
        <EditableCell onphoneTableUpdate={this.props.onphoneTableUpdate} cellData={{
          type: "Field2",
          value: this.props.phone.Field2,
          id: this.props.phone.id
        }}/>
        <EditableCell onphoneTableUpdate={this.props.onphoneTableUpdate} cellData={{
          type: "Field3",
          value: this.props.phone.Field3,
          id: this.props.phone.id
        }}/>
        <EditableCell onphoneTableUpdate={this.props.onphoneTableUpdate} cellData={{
          type: "Field4",
          value: this.props.phone.Field4,
          id: this.props.phone.id
        }}/>
        <EditableCell onphoneTableUpdate={this.props.onphoneTableUpdate} cellData={{
          type: "Field5",
          value: this.props.phone.Field5,
          id: this.props.phone.id
        }}/>
        <td className="del-cell">
          <input type="button" onClick={this.onDelEvent.bind(this)} value="REMOVE" className="del-btn"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );

  }

}
class EditableCell extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <td>
        <input type='text' name={this.props.cellData.type} id={this.props.cellData.id} value={this.props.cellData.value} onChange={this.props.onphoneTableUpdate}/>
      </td>
    );

  }

}


export default Phone;
```

Comment: As a general recommendation, it is typically better to make a separate file for each component, or at least each major component. Three 100-line files are easier to navigate than one 300-line file, especially when each file is named after the component it exports.

Answer (score 0):

At the top, you should have this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

`PropTypes` is not exported directly from `react`. Also, `displayForms` should be `DisplayForms` - React components have to start with a capital letter.

Comment: Hi Tim , Thanks for both of your comments , the displayForms class is part of the inbuilt template and by default it is named that way , it's a pre-built bootstrap template for react we are using , I will change the name though and about your other comment so you suggest a seperate component to be built for each table and that would make my life easier you feel ? Will follow your lead

Comment: Ah, okay, I guess you're not using JSX in that template then. Is it running correctly with the import statement fixed?

Comment: Yes it is running , right now the example I referred here : https://codepen.io/Shamiul_Hoque/pen/LNavdZ has it just for one table , I want to have 2 more tables with the same functionality but individually on the same page , this is preventing me from accomplishing it

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Did you replace `import React, { PropTypes , Component } from 'react';` with the two lines of code in my answer, and if so, did that fix the error you were asking about in your question?

Comment: Hi Tim , Yes I did that , I have posted the updated code And I am getting this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined. address is defined according to my understanding, Please provide your inputs.

Comment: That would be because none of the objects in your `addresses` array contain a `name` property, which you are trying to access.

Comment: Thanks that's resolved but now I am unable to enter anything in the field whenever I add a row in the table, I thought ev.target.value 's whole purpose was this , I am unable to enter anything in the rows that I add,I have posted the updated code

Comment: I would recommend you take some time to really learn React and JavaScript. It will help you more to learn how to debug and fix these kinds of problems yourself than it will to ask how to fix each issue individually.

Comment: Thanks I have been reading up on it for the past 6 weeks ever since I started working on react, I am a newbie in react, I was able to resolve the previous issue and have 2 tables rendered out along with the form , Now I want to retrieve values from the tables apart from the form , Since there are 2 tables how do I differentiate and get the data , since Phone is a different component how do I get the data from a child component , I have read the docs and referred a few examples too , the table vals are being retreieved in Handleaddress function with evt.target.value . Please suggest.

Comment: I think the values being entered in the table are being stored in state objects products and phones as a key value pair how do I access the phones state object which is a child component in forms which is the parent component

Comment: Hi folks , I have the previous issues fixed , Now I am trying to access the child components' state objects from parent component , I tried call back and so forth but was not able to get it , I am trying to access phones and emails state objects in the components , Can you suggest anything else , Any help is much appreciated